# Pandas importing error " ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas._typing' "

Tags: python, pandas, import, anaconda, importerror

When I try to import `pandas`, it throws an error. I cannot import `pandas`. I re-install pandas but it keeps ont throwing the same error.

I tried running it in a local prompt and in a jupyter notebook. I think it may conflict with the pip version so I removed the package from pip. Currently I just have the conda version but still same error. What can I do?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "havatahmin.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 144, in <module>
    from pandas.io.api import (
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\api.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.excel._base import ExcelFile, ExcelWriter, read_excel
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers import TextParser
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.io.parsers.readers import (
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas._typing import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas._typing' (C:\Anaconda\envs\ED\lib\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py)
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I confirm, it is a reproducible bug in `pandas==1.3.1`.

A workaround is to downgrade it to some earlier version, e.g. `pip install pandas==1.3.0`.

The woarkaround can be tested in build `20210717` of our python (3.8) CUDA-enabled containers:

```
docker run -d --rm --name ml-gpu-py38-cuda112-cust -p 8888:8888 -v /home/mir:/home/jovyan mirekphd/ml-gpu-py38-cuda112-cust:20210717 && docker logs -f ml-gpu-py38-cuda112-cust
```

Has it been already reported to pandas devs on Github?

Update: The issue still persists, so I've provided a reproducible example to Pandas devs in [#42506](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42506).

Comment: I also install python-dateutil and pytz. It's solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

This error can occur for multiple reasons.

- `pip install pandas --ignore-installed` will break pandas between `1.3.0` and `1.3.1` because it does not remove old files from `site-packages`, thus the import error. If this is the case, you can re-install pandas without this flag.

```
pip install --force-reinstall pandas
```

- Mixing conda and pip may also break pandas, as discussed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/42506). For that matter, if you use conda, try to stick with it *then* install missing packages with pip. More guidelines on how to [use pip in a Conda environment](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

Comment: Pandas should be arguably made robust to such multiple versions co-existence. I've had this happen several times for various packages, without mixing installers (pip only) or using special install flags. Users can for instance have their own version of a library installed locally (in the user folder), and another one in a Docker container they run using this folder.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't see any scenario where you would handle multiple versions of Pandas.