# ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas 1.3.2 in a Conda environment.

When importing pandas on a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'DtypeArg' from 'pandas._typing' (C:\Users\tone_\anaconda3\envs\spyder\lib\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py)
```

I've seen similar questions, but so far no solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried dwongrading to pandas 1.3.0 ? This seems to be a common bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer provided in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68601733/9330208) it is a bug in `pandas==1.3.1`.

A possible solution is to downgrade it to some earlier version, e.g `pip install pandas==1.3.0`

Comment: Exactly, I saw that post too. Thinking the issue was related with pandas 1.3.1 I upgraded to 1.3.2

Comment: Did you try to downgrade it? Maybe the error still persist in 1.3.2.

Comment: I'm trying that just now

Answer (score 3):

It worked with me when I downgraded the pandas from panadas=1.3.5 to pandas=1.3.0 and I am using conda enviroment

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am also using pandas 1.3.5 and encountered this issue, thanks for sharing.